# How does the Protected merit manifest?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

From VtR (299):

> ### Protected (••)
>
> Having tasted your blood, a Kindred has developed a strong connection to you as a result. Further, he has some vested interest seeing to your long-term survival. If you’re in danger, he knows about it, and he may come to you as quickly as possible.
>
> **Prerequisite**: Ghoul or Human
>
> **Effect**: If your character is in danger, her regnant senses it, and can spend a Willpower point to coincidentally arrive on the scene in time to save you.

How does this coincidental arrival work? Is it just plot armor, or is it magic, like Vitae teleporting through Invictus oaths? What happens if ghoul is threatened during day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Plot armor; there's no temporal or translocative power inherent to the merit.
2. Since the merit says the regnant senses it, we can assume it's something strong enough to disturb the daysleep. Since acting on it is not compulsory ("he *may* come to you as quickly as possible"), either nothing happens, or the vampire rouses from slumber using something like the system on page 98.